# customizing Tab text color, stacked color, and swipe functionality in Xamarin Android?

Tags: tabs, xamarin.android

I have three tabs in xamarin android, I have used tab Host to create those tabs. Now, I want to change the text color in those tabs, and I want to use the swipe effect just like the Tabbed Page in Xamarin Forms. How can I achieve this? Please do tell me the library also ,if required?

Comment: You could try to use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to change the text color in those tabs, and I want to use the swipe effect just like the Tabbed Page in Xamarin Forms

You could use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), Usage like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/tablayout"
       app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
       app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

      <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
          android:text="tab 1"/>
      <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
          android:text="tab 2"/>
      <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
          android:text="tab 3"/>

   </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Attribute to change the text color :

```
 app:tabTextColor         -->   The default text color to be applied to tabs.
 app:tabSelectedTextColor -->   The text color to be applied to the currently selected tab. 
 app:tabIndicatorColor    -->   Color of the indicator used to show the currently selected tab.
```

Effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/760RY.gif).

> use the swipe effect just like the Tabbed Page in Xamarin Forms

In `Xamarin.Forms`, tabs is associated with `Page`, actually when it render in native Android, it was associated with [ViewPager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/#Pages). So if you want implement the swipe effect feature, you have to write the code by yourself. For more details, you could read the [document](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/xamarin-android-working-material-design-tablayout-viewpager-hoang-le).

EDIT :

To use `TabLayout`, you have to add `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` nuget package.

**EDIT 2 ；**

Here is a simple demo about implement the swipe effect :

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> mFragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
    private List<string> mTabTitles = new List<string>();
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        TabLayout tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tablayout);
        ViewPager viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.view_pager);

        initTab();
        mFragments.Add(new Fragment1());
        mFragments.Add(new Fragment1());
        mFragments.Add(new Fragment1());
        mFragments.Add(new Fragment1());

        viewPager.Adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, mFragments,mTabTitles);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void initTab()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            mTabTitles.Add("Tab" + i);
        }
    }
}

public class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private List<string> mTabTitles;
    private static  int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 4;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager, List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments, List<string> tabTitles):base(fragmentManager)
    {
        mTabTitles = tabTitles;
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem(int position)
    {
        Fragment1 testFragment = new Fragment1();
        return testFragment;
    }

    public override int Count => FRAGMENT_COUNT;

    public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
    {
        return new Java.Lang.String(mTabTitles[position]);
    }
}
```

`axml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    >
  </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWnG.gif).

**EDIT 3** :

In my demo, `Fragment` should use `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`, code like this :

```
public class Fragment1 : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to set Tab text in android.support.design.widget.TabItem. And, I also wanted, to open a fragment on clicking or swiping the tabs?
How can I do that?

Comment: yes, it is showing android:text attribute is not declared.

Comment: Actually, you still can use this attribute in your app and it works fine.

Comment: and how do I enable swipe on tabs and open Different fragment on click??

Comment: the code is working fine, but now I am not able to swipe?? Can you help me out?

Comment: viewPager.Adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, mFragments,mTabTitles);
 showing error on this line, cannot call the constructor of View PagerAdapter. Support fragment Manager is not valid in the given context

Comment: where are you adding your second fragment?? everything is running fine but at the end app crashes

Comment: @aman, I add the fragment by using `mFragments.Add(new Fragment1())`, the four fragment are same.

Comment: @aman, you could open a new question and post the exception for a better solution.

Comment: just one more thing can you tell me the click event that I will get on clicking any of the tab??

Comment: @aman, when you use `tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager)` method, this click event was handled by system.