# Xamarin Forms: How to change text color of selected tab using TabbedPageRenderer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing Tabs using TabbedPageRenderer. I am not able to change **text color** of selected tab(Only getting change selected tab **icon color**).
Below is `MyTabbedPageRenderer.cs` class

```
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    bool setup;
    ViewPager pager;
    TabLayout layout;

    public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    { }

    protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
    {
        base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
        tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.Custom_tab_layou);
        var imageview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
        var tv = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        tv.SetText(tab.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        imageview.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);  
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (setup)
            return;
        if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
        {
            pager = (ViewPager)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
            layout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);

            setup = true;
            ColorStateList colors = null;

            //using xml file
            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
                colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab, Forms.Context.Theme);
            else
                colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);

            for (int i = 0; i < layout.TabCount; i++)
            {
                var tab = layout.GetTabAt(i);
                var icon = tab.Icon;

                Android.Views.View view = GetChildAt(i);
                if (view is TabLayout)
                    layout = (TabLayout)view;

                if (icon != null)
                {
                    icon = Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.Wrap(icon);
                    Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.SetTintList(icon, colors);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This `xml` file applied for changing selected tab & text color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:color="#E2725B" 
          android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <item app:tabSelectedTextColor="#F3E5AB" />
</selector>
```

styles using for `MainActivity`

```
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

style using for splashActivity

```
<style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent 
   ="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  </style>
```

Tabbar.axml file below

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#BF94E4"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#DFFF00"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Below screenshot of output where only icon color getting changed

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Xamarin Forms: How to change text color of selected tab using TabbedPageRenderer

There is no need to use `TabbedPageRenderer` to change the selected tab text color, you can change it directly **Via XML attributes**.

In your **`Resource\layout\Tabbar.axml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"

        app:tabTextColor="@color/your_unselected_text_color"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/your_selected_text_color"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your_indicator_color"
     />
```

## Update:

Give your `TextView` a `ColorStateList` will solve this issue. In your `MyTabbedPageRenderer` `SetTabIcon` method:

```
protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
{
    base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
    tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.Custom_tab_layou);

    var imageview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
    var tv = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);

    tv.SetText(tab.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
    imageview.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);

    ColorStateList colors2 = null;

    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
        colors2 = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab, Forms.Context.Theme);
    else
        colors2 = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);
    tv.SetTextColor(colors2);
}
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHzvr.png).

Comment: Renderer not using only for Text color, It is for showing tabs on bottom side, icons size etc..

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal, if you need to change the selected text color, you could do it in your `Tabbar.axml`.

Comment: @YS I am only able to change `tabIndicatorColor` from axml. Not changing `app:tabSelectedTextColor`. When i remove `android:theme` all tabs text color becomes black. My axml is exactly same what you have posed.

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal, why did you remove `android:theme`? And what are you mean "Not changing `tabIndicatorColor`"? could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: See my updated comment. I removed it for checking purpose, again i added that. Once you see my updated question where i will keep all relevant stuff

Comment: @PriyankaAgrawal, would you mind sharing a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo?

Comment: Here I have uploaded my project please have a look on it
[Get demo project](https://github.com/PinkoAgrawal/FormsTab)

Answer (score 0):

See if this might helpful to you [How to change selected Tab text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077047/customizing-tab-text-color-stacked-color-and-swipe-functionality-in-xamarin-an)

 you can use TabLayout instead like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/tablayout"
   app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
   app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
   app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
      android:text="tab 1"/>
  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
      android:text="tab 2"/>
  <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
      android:text="tab 3"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I am not using tab android.support.design.widget.TabLayout from axml. I am using it from xamarin forms project.