# Customize Tabbed page for android in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, renderer

I want to create this kind of design for bottom tabs (change background color for selected tab of tabbed page in xamarin forms)

[image]

I want to fix the issue on android. Plz help me! Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you're running into, and what have you tried so far to fix? Please include a [mcve] of your application (using [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), no images please!). We can't help you fix your issue unless we know what the issue is in the first place.

Comment: thanks! I want to change background color for selected tab on android

Comment: Try use `TabbedPageRenderer` to deal with it.

If you want set bottom bars,can refer to this [link][1]. There are many ways to try.

And if want change background color ,you can refer to this [link][2].

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT: your linsk have broken in your comment.

Comment: Sorry,i found that.Youc an refer to this link.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49707608/xamarin-forms-how-to-change-text-color-of-selected-tab-using-tabbedpagerenderer).However, you should change some code in this.Custome page xml in android is needed.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT i want to change background color for tab not text color

Answer (score 0):

Need more clarification on the issue, if you want to move the tab bar to bottom like in iOS, below code helps you.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        x:Class="XXX.Views.TabbedPage" 
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#a39d9f"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#007aff"
        android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="false"
        BackgroundColor="#f8f8f8"
        Padding="5,0,5,0" >

</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: thanks for comment. but this solution not fix my issue.
I want to change backround color for selected tab of tabbed page on andorid.